# Attach ClickEvent to a button via JavaScript / JQuery / Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a small game that involves smurf and toadstools.
I've been able to already make this. [Can't do direct image :/ Reputation = 6] http://gyazo.com/e9cab4b04e6735712cf67e69c689fb7b

Each of the white / red and white / blue circles is a button in it's own seperate div. What I wan't to do now is "attach" a clickEvent handler to each of those buttons so that whenever a button get's pressed, the image switches to either blank or the red and white ones.

The buttons are created with code as below:

```
    var circle = document.createElement('button');
    column.appendChild(circle);
```

and each button has it's own ID.

So is there any simple and easy way to make each button respond to a click like mentioned above?

The data I would need later is most importantly the ID of the clicked button. Since it's id has a reference to the row and column it belongs in.

Comment: if you're trying just plain javascript, you can use circle.addEventListener and if you want to use jquery then you can just use $('button').on('click', function(){ /*your code here*/ });

Comment: @Sushil I can retrieve the id of the clicked button via both ways, right? If so, THX :D + (Each button has a seperate id)

Comment: @Sushil Tested and I get a mouseEvent back that contains the button ID! Thx

Comment: let me post this as a solution then. please accept it as an answer @MrKickkiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **event triggered function** can be attached to an **element** through **javascript** using the `addEventListener()` method.
The syntax of said method is the following:

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);
```

For instance, in your case:

```
circle.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

The code above would obviously need the function `myFunction()` to be previously defined, however, the function can also be defined within the method itself:

```
circle.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //your function
});
```

You can learn more about this method [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, I would do something like this:

```
var circle = document.createElement('button');
circle.className = "nameOfTheClass";
column.appendChild(circle);
```

Then jQuery bind click events on each object of class nameOfTheClass:

```
$('.nameOfTheClass').click(function(){
     alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

PS: You could also use jquery to create your dom element but since you only asked how to bind it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot more easily by adding your click event to the buttons' parent rather than to each button, like so:

```
column.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var target=event.target,id=target.id;
    if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="button"){
        // do stuff ...
    }
},0);
```

This way you don't have to worry about buttons added to your `column` element later on in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying plain `javascript` use

```
circle.addEventListener("click", function(){
    /* your code here */
});
```

or if you intend to use `Jquery` then use

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
 /*your code here*/ 
});
```

note this will apply on all the buttons of the page. if you want to use it for a specific button, then you can just use `id` or the `class`.

hope this helps.